# Expand Telerik RadTreeView (for ASP.net AJAX) on load

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik, radtreeview

I'm wondering why I can't find a straight way to expand all nodes of a static RadTreeView on page load. I first traversed all its properties both from properties pane of Visual Studio and also I checked it from code-behind. I didn't find any single property to tell it to open it in expanded mode. Then I looked at the Telerik's website and unfortunately I didn't find any server-side solution to make it load in expanded mode.

Do you know any ways/tricks to load it in expanded mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer (expanding from code-behind):

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            foreach (RadTreeNode rtn in RTVControl.Nodes)
            {
                rtn.ExpandChildNodes();
                rtn.Expanded = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This could also help somebody. [More Information here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-client-expanding-collapsing.html)

```
//Javascript
var treeView = $find("<%= RadTreeView2.ClientID %>");
var nodes = treeView.get_allNodes();
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].get_nodes() != null) {
        nodes[i].expand();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub RadTreeView1_NodeCreated(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs) Handles RadTreeView1.NodeCreated
    e.Node.Expanded = True
End Sub
```